# On first principles of differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

**Question**

Let

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac {a} {x - 1} [3\sin(x - 1) - 2\tan(\ln x)]\ , & \text{if } \frac 1 2 < x < 1\ , \\
b\ , & \text{if } x = 1\ , \\
\int^{x^2}_{4(x - 1)} e^{x + [\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t\ , & \text{if } x > 1\ .
\end{cases}$$

Given that $f$ is differentiable, find the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

---

**My working**

For $f$ to be differentiable, $f$ must first be continuous.

$$\implies \lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f(x)$$

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x) & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \frac {a[3\sin(x - 1) - 2\tan(\ln x)]} {x - 1}
\\[5 mm] & =
a\lim\limits_{x\to1^-} [3\cos(x - 1) - \frac 2 x \sec^2(\ln x)]
\\[5 mm] & =
a
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x) & =
b
\end{align}

$$\implies a = b $$

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f(x) & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \int^{x^2}_{4(x - 1)} e^{x + [\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t
\\[5 mm] & =
\int^1_0 e^{1 + [\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t
\\[5 mm] & =
e\int^1_0 e^{[\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t
\end{align}

Then, I am stuck, as evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f(x)$ does not seem to be that straightforward. I also know that if $f$ is differentiable at some $d$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to d^-} \frac {f(x) - f(d)} {x - d} = \lim\limits_{x\to d^+} \frac {f(x) - f(d)} {x - d}$ and I would usually find these limits to obtain some more equations, but in this case, I do not seem to be able to arrive with more "usable" relations between $a$ and/or $b$ and/or $c$.

Any help/hints/intuition on how I should proceed will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: There seems to be an error in the $c$ bit - $e^{(\ln[1+t])^c} \neq [t+1]^c$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Thank you for the spot! Please see my edited post.

Comment: Are you sure that such values for $a,b$ and $c$ even exist ?

Comment: @Digitallis Yup. It is implied through the phrasing of the question. I have also managed to work it out, if you are interested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa. After 5 days, I think I have managed to figure it out. Posting my answer here for anyone who is interested :)

For $f$ to be differentiable, $f$ must first be continuous.

$$\implies \lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f(x)$$

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x) & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \frac {a[3\sin(x - 1) - 2\tan(\ln x)]} {x - 1}
\\[5 mm] & =
a\lim\limits_{x\to1^-} [3\cos(x - 1) - \frac 2 x \sec^2(\ln x)]
\\[5 mm] & =
a
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x) & =
b
\end{align}

$$\implies a = b $$

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f(x) & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \int^{x^2}_{4(x - 1)} e^{x + [\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t
\\[5 mm] & =
\int^1_0 e^{1 + [\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t
\\[5 mm] & =
e\int^1_0 e^{[\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t
\end{align}

$$\implies \frac a e = \int^1_0 e^{[\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t$$

$$\because f\ \mathrm {is\ differentiable}$$

$$\therefore f'(1)\ \mathrm {must\ exist}$$

$$\implies \lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \frac {f(x) - f(1)} {x - 1} = \lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \frac {f(x) - f(1)} {x - 1}$$

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \frac {f(x) - f(1)} {x - 1} & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \frac {\frac {a} {x - 1} [3\sin(x - 1) - 2\tan(\ln x)] - a} {x - 1}
\\[5 mm] & =
a \lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \frac {3\sin(x - 1) - 2\tan(\ln x) - (x - 1)} {(x - 1)^2}
\\[5 mm] & =
a \lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \frac {3\cos(x - 1) - \frac {2\sec^2(\ln x)} {x} - 1} {2(x - 1)}
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac a 2 \lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \left[-3\sin(x - 1) - \frac {4\sec^2(\ln x)\tan(\ln x) - 2\sec^2(\ln x)} {x^2}\right]
\\[5 mm] & =
a
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \frac {f(x) - f(1)} {x - 1} & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \frac {\int^{x^2}_{4(x - 1)} e^{x + [\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t - a} {x - 1}
\\[5 mm] & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \frac {e^x \int^{x^2}_{4(x - 1)} e^{[\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t - a} {x - 1}
\\[5 mm] & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \frac {e^x \int^{x^2}_{4(x - 1)} e^{[\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t - a} {x - 1}
\\[5 mm] & =
\lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \left[e^x \int^{x^2}_{4(x - 1)} e^{[\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t + e^x(2xe^{[\ln (x^2 + 1)]^c} - 4e^{[\ln (4x - 3)]^c})\right]
\\[5 mm] & =
e \int^1_0 e^{[\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t + e[2e^{(\ln 2)^c} - 4]
\end{align}

$$\because \frac a e = \int^1_0 e^{[\ln (t + 1)]^c}\ \mathrm {d}t$$

$$\therefore \lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \frac {f(x) - f(1)} {x - 1} = a + e[2e^{(\ln 2)^c} - 4]$$

$$\because \lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \frac {f(x) - f(1)} {x - 1} = \lim\limits_{x\to1^+} \frac {f(x) - f(1)} {x - 1}$$

$$\therefore a = a + e[2e^{(\ln 2)^c} - 4]$$

$$\implies c = 1$$

$$\because c = 1$$

\begin{align}
\therefore \frac a e & = \int^1_0 (t + 1)\ \mathrm {d}t
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac 1 2 [(t + 1)^2]^{t = 1}_{t = 0}
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac 3 2
\end{align}

$$\implies a = \frac 3 2 e$$

$$\therefore a = \frac 3 2 e = b\ \mathrm {and}\ c = 1$$

Comment: Haven't checked it all out yet but there are some minor mistakes that don't change alot. You say $f$ differentiable $\implies \lim_{x \to 1^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} f'(x)$ isn't this assuming the continuity of the derivative itself ? You should rather write $f$ differentiable $\implies $ that $$ f'(1) = \lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$$

Comment: @Digitallis Oh yes. Many typos on my part because I tend to copy and paste the formatting from earlier parts and then "rewrite" the "content", so I do not have to type out everything again. I believe the answer is alright now :) but do let me know if there are still more errors!

Comment: It looks good and your solution checks out when plotting the graph.